# Optimization of integrands: Can we find extrema of a function defined as an integral?

Tags: integration, optimization, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Given constants $r, \alpha$, I would like to find the function $p: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ subject to the constraint $$\int_0^1p(t)r^tdt = 1$$ which minimizes $$\int_0^1e^{-\alpha p(t)}dt$$.

How can I do this?

My work so far:

- If $r = 1$, then $p$ is uniform, by symmetry. Can I somehow incorporate $r$ into the integrand, and define a new function $P(t) = p(t)/r^t$, so that $P(t)$ must be uniform?
- Can I use Lagrange multipliers?  Their standard usage is finding a *point* where extrema occur, not a *function*.
- Can I use Calculus of Variations (and least action)? I have encountered these but am not proficient in them.

Comment: Calculus of variations with a Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: "If $r=1$, then $p$ is uniform, by symmetry." What symmetry?

Comment: Simplify things a bit by writing your constraint as $\int_0^1\, p(t)e^{bt}\, dt = 1$. Find the stationary point(s) of $J(p) := \int_0^1\,e^{-ap(t)}\, dt + \lambda\int_0^1\, p(t)e^{bt}\, dt$ where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier. Start with computing the first variation of $J$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Symmetry over $t$.  If $r = 1$, the integrand does not depend on $t$ other than through $p(t)$, and so therefore $p$ should not depend on $t$ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with $J(p) := \int_0^1\, e^{-ap(t)}\, dt + \lambda\int_0^1\, p(t)e^{bt}\, dt,$ the calculus of variations is the proper tool. Informally, if $p$ is a stationary point, then with $p + \varepsilon w$, for small $\varepsilon$ and pretty arbitrary function $w$, the first variation
\begin{align}
(J(p + \varepsilon w) - J(p))/\varepsilon &= \int_0^1\, e^{-ap(t)}\, \frac{e^{-a\varepsilon w(t)} - 1}{\varepsilon}\, dt
+ \lambda\int_0^1\, w(t)e^{bt}\, dt \\
&= \int_0^1\, (-a e^{-ap(t)} + \lambda e^{bt})w(t)\, dt + O(\varepsilon)
\end{align}
is zero. This leads to the stationary point satisfying $-a e^{-ap(t)} + \lambda e^{bt} = 0$, that is
$$p(t) = -a^{-1}\log(\lambda/a) - (b/a)t,$$
with $\lambda$ being chosen so that $\int_0^1\,p(t)e^{bt}\, dt = 1$.